# How can I define Keycloak RBAC in a Laravel API app

Tags: php, laravel, keycloak

I am working on a Laravel api, and I want to integrate a fine-grained authorization using Keycloak.

I am authenticating the user with a Vue.js SPA app using a **public** Keycloak client (`keycloak-js`). How can I now connect my Laravel app to a **confidential** Keycloak client to check if the user has *permissions* to access certain *resources*.

I tried using [robsontenorio/laravel-keycloak-guard](https://github.com/robsontenorio/laravel-keycloak-guard) but apparently it only checks user roles and token, so it doesn't give the ability to define *permissions*, *policies*, ...